# Counting function for the number of zeros of the real part of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

The counting function for the number of complex zeros of the Riemann $\zeta$ function up to height $T$ is well known.  I am looking for a reference that gives essentially analogous counting functions for the number of zeros of the real part of $\zeta$ (on the critical line), and likewise the counting function for the imaginary part. Thanks, Andrey

Comment: Maybe you're not anticipating what kind of answer there'll be: zeros of the real (or imaginary) part will be ("real") _curves_ in the complex plane... _not_ isolated points... (And, of course, the intersections of these two batches of curves _are_ the isolated points which are the zeros of zeta...)

Comment: By the term "essentially" I basically meant their zeros on the critical line (not that other vertical lines would not be of interest).

Comment: Ah, ok! I did wonder. :) Maybe modify your question accordingly?